# Error: Multiple inheritance from classes 'UICollectionViewController' and 'UICollectionViewLayout'

Tags: ios, swift, class, inheritance, xcode8

In Xcode 8 I'm trying to make a subclass of UICollectionViewController and UICollectionViewLayout but I get the error:

> Multiple inheritance from classes 'UICollectionViewController' and 'UICollectionViewLayout'

but they have different parents classes. I'm trying to follow http://nshint.io/blog/2015/07/16/uicollectionviews-now-have-easy-reordering/ tutorial for reorder custom size cells

```
class WordCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewLayout {
    // ...
    override func invalidationContext(forInteractivelyMovingItems targetIndexPaths: [IndexPath], withTargetPosition targetPosition: CGPoint, previousIndexPaths: [IndexPath], previousPosition: CGPoint) -> UICollectionViewLayoutInvalidationContext {
            var context = super.invalidationContext(forInteractivelyMovingItems: targetIndexPaths, withTargetPosition: targetPosition, previousIndexPaths: previousIndexPaths, previousPosition: previousPosition)

        return context
    }
}
```

Comment: Why exactly do you need to inherit from both? I can't see a good reason for this.

Comment: you CANNOT inherit from more than one class. You can adopt multiple protocols, but inherit only from one class.

Comment: @luk2302 Got it covered :)!

Comment: @Ike10 I've just added some more informations

Comment: See my answer for an explanation of why what you're doing is not possible. I will edit it to show how to handle this situation properly.

Comment: Added a link to a tutorial on the matter of making a custom `UICollectionViewLayout`! Hope it helps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beyond my comment. Swift **DOES NOT** support multiple inheritances. `UICollectionViewLayout` is a class, so since your `WorldCollectionViewController` is already inheriting from `UICollectionViewController` you cannot inherit from `UICollectionViewLayout` (you also don't want to). This:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

}
```

is not multiple inheritances but a single inheritance from the `UIViewController` and conformance to a protocol `UITextFieldDelegate`.

You can read more about what protocols are and how to use them here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html

Essentially protocols are like a set of guidelines. These guidelines specify methods and properties. If a class **conforms** to a protocol then it must implement the methods and properties described in the protocol's guidelines. For example:

```
protocol hasAVariablePotato {
   var potato: String! { get set }
}
```

Any object that conforms to this protocol **must** have a variable (not a let constant) `potato` that is of type `String` and implicitly unwrapped. Like so:

```
class PotatoFarmer: Farmer, hasAVariablePotato {

}
```

The above `PotatoFarmer` class inherits from a `Farmer` class and **but does not conform** to `hasAVariablePotato` because there is no `potato` var! So the above will generate the error:

> Type 'PotatoFarmer' does not conform to protocol 'hasAVariablePotato'

To fix this error **the programmer must add** in the properties and methods of the protocol, like so:

```
class PotatoFarmer: Farmer, hasAVariablePotato {
   var potato: String!
}
```

The error will now disappear because you have **conformed** to the protocol.

For your situation you want to make **separate subclasses** of `UICollectionViewLayout` and `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes`. To see how to do this check here (a great FREE tutorial on the subject): 
https://www.raywenderlich.com/107439/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest

Answer (score 0):

Swift doesn't support multiple inheritances. UICollectionViewController and UICollectionViewLayout both are class. Don't inherit both the class. You can use below code instead

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class Test:UICollectionViewLayout{

    override func invalidationContext(forInteractivelyMovingItems targetIndexPaths: [IndexPath], withTargetPosition targetPosition: CGPoint, previousIndexPaths: [IndexPath], previousPosition: CGPoint) -> UICollectionViewLayoutInvalidationContext {
        var context = super.invalidationContext(forInteractivelyMovingItems: targetIndexPaths, withTargetPosition: targetPosition, previousIndexPaths: previousIndexPaths, previousPosition: previousPosition)

            return context
    }
}
```